# android: How to insert a bottom aligned view without layout.xml?

Tags: android

I want to insert views dynamically by using addView method, like this.

```
TextView view = new TextView(this);
view.setText("foo");
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
parentView.addView(view);
```

How can I align bottom the inserted view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this you will get the result:

```
    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.llayout);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("foo");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, textView.getId());
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);

    parent.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try to use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `ViewGroup`, like this:

```
    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_parent);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("foo");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, tv.getId());
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    parent.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will align textview with bottom

```
   TextView view = new TextView(this);
   view.setText("foo");

   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, view.getId());

   view.setLayoutParams(params);
   ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.viewgroup);
   parentView.addView(view);
```

Comment: I think you have to set view id for using view.getId(), If It doesn't, maybe get null point error. don't you think?